# RegEx: Smallest possible match or nongreedy match

Tags: .net, regex, regex-greedy, non-greedy

How do I tell RegEx (.NET version) to get the smallest valid match instead of the largest?

Answer (score 310, accepted):

For a regular expression like `.*` or `.+`, append a question mark (`.*?` or `.+?`) to match as few characters as possible. To optionally match a section `(?:blah)?` but without matching unless absolutely necessary, use something like `(?:blah){0,1}?`. For a repeating match (either using `{n,}` or `{n,m}` syntax) append a question mark to try to match as few as possible (e.g. `{3,}?` or `{5,7}?`).

The documentation on [regular expression quantifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3206d374(v=vs.110).aspx) may also be helpful.

Comment: Line2 "but without matching unless absolutely necessary": What does this mean?

Comment: Won't this '{0,1}' match nothing because of the 0? Why don't use '{1}' instead?

Comment: Regular expressions are greedy by default, which means they try to match as much as possible. Adding the question mark right after the braces means that it will try to match the fewest possible times, but will still match if it can't avoid it. Just using '{1}' means that it must match exactly once.

Comment: This is not what lazy matching does. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35944441

Answer (score 102):

The non-greedy operator, `?`. Like so:

```
.*?
```

Answer (score 74):

The non greedy operator does not mean the shortest possible match:

> abcabk

`a.+?k` will match the entire string (in this example) instead of only the last three signs.

I'd like to actually find the smallest possible match instead.

That is that last possible match for '`a`' to still allow all matches for `k`.

I guess the only way to do that is to make use of an expression like:

```
a[^a]+?k
```

```js
const haystack = 'abcabkbk';
const paternNonGreedy = /a.+?k/;
const paternShortest = /a[^a]+?k/;

const matchesNonGreedy = haystack.match(paternNonGreedy);
const matchesShortest = haystack.match(paternShortest);

console.log('non greedy: ',matchesNonGreedy[0]);
console.log('shortest: ', matchesShortest[0]);
```

Comment: Or search in reverse order, starting at the end, when matches are nested: "(ab(abk)bk)".

Comment: @LBogaardt how would one search in reverse order? don't get it

Comment: @LBogaardt Still open question: How would one search in reverse order? Lets say I want to get `cab`. If my input is `caaacab` and I search for `a.*?b` it will return the full string instead of the short match inside. How would I search backwards from the `b`?

Comment: Reverse the string, then apply the regex.

Comment: I don't really see how reversing the string would help at all. In the string of the example it would only work because there is only one k, add another k at the end and reversing the string will end up giving you the exact same problem.

Comment: @C4u Try `c[^cb]*b`, it'll match the shortest path between `c` and `b`

Comment: This is super helpful. For people like me trying to understand what's going on here the generic form is `START[^START]*?END` (where START and END are your start and end character regexs). It essentially means "match anything from START to END where the in-between characters do not include START again"

Comment: I suppose this would only work when START is a single character?

Comment: @derekantrican Thanks for this. I was trying to grab the comma-bounded fragment of a sentence that talks about a leaf's venation, but kept getting the fragments before it despite using a lazy search. `,[^,]*?(venation|reticulat)[[:print:]]*?,` worked!

Answer (score 0):

A negative lookahead would help here

Example:

```
a...a.....a..b


a.*?b            =>   a...a.....a..b
a(((?!a).)*?)b   =>   a..b
```

a and b can be larger

```
start...start......start..end


start.*?end                =>   start...start.....start..end
start(((?!start).)*?)end   =>   start..end
```

Note: this won't find the shortest match in the string.

```
a...a.....a..b.a.b


a.*?b            =>   a...a.....a..b
a(((?!a).)*?)b   =>   a..b
```

This still finds `a..b` not `a.b` so it's not "Smallest possible match". I'm not sure you can find smallest possible match with regex. You could find all matches and then in those results find the smallest.