# Regular Expression to select substring

Tags: java, regex

I have input string

```
DISPLAY_MSG='Kumar + sajdhjhasd - Type' 
              and  ID=156090 
              and RESOURCE_KEY='Ascend.ElementMaster.kumar_type.desc' 
              and  LOCALE='en_US'
```

I want to match only  `DISPLAY_MSG='Kumar + sajdhjhasd - Type'` but using this expression

```
DISPLAY_MSG='[\\w\\W\\s\\S]*
```

matching whole string. How can I select only string between only those two single codes after

```
DISPLAY_MSG=
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use **ungreedy** quantifier. Try this:

```
DISPLAY_MSG='[\\w\\W\\s\\S]*?'
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution working... but I made little change to my expression to include and as well to replace from DSIPLAY_MSG to it's next and(this and can occur one or more times) DISPLAY_MSG='[\\w\\W\\s\\S]*?'[\\s]*and{0,1}. but it was not matching. What could be the case?

Answer (score 3):

This regex is quite nonsensical.

`[\w\W\s\S]` means: Match a character if it is either alphanumeric or non-alphanumeric or whitespace or non-whitespace. The exact same result can be achieved by `(?s).`.

Only in JavaScript (where the `(?s)` option that allows the dot to match newlines isn't available, it makes sense to write `[\s\S]` instead. But `[\w\W\s\S]` is definitely overkill.

So, a better solution using lazy quantifiers would be

```
DISPLAY_MSG='(?s).*?'
```

But even better would be to actually specify what is allowed between the quotes, and that usually is anything *but*  a quote:

```
DISPLAY_MSG='[^']*'
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try using non-greedy quantifier to reduce the match to smallest possible length.

[RegEx: Smallest possible match or nongreedy match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919982/regex-smallest-possible-match)

Following is a good example http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util.regex/greedy.html