# regex : match string between two strings

Tags: regex

I have a string like this :

```
[01/09/2015 00:00:47]       INFO=54646486432154646 from=steve   idfrom=55516654455457       to=jone       idto=5552045646464 guid=100021623456461451463   n
um=6    text=hi my number is 0 811 22 1/12   status=new      survstatus=new
```

I want to extract the text field, the result should like this :

```
hi my number is 0 811 22 1/12
```

This is what I tried as regex :

```
text=(.*)status
```

And it gives me this :

```
hi my number is 0 811 22 1/12   status=new      survstatus=new
```

So it's not what I want, how can I get rid of two last fields?

Thanks.

Comment: Use `.*?` instead of `.*`. [See greedy vs non-greedy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075130/difference-between-and-for-regex/3075532#3075532)

Comment: @HamZa Thanks HamZa, you saved my day :)

Comment: @HamZa post it as an answer :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RegEx: Smallest possible match or nongreedy match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919982/regex-smallest-possible-match-or-nongreedy-match)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is `text=(.*?)status`, thank @HamZa for the quick answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use:

```
\btext=(.*?)\bstatus=
```

in order avoid matching status in `hi my status is 0`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is even better.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your data is tab-delimited.  If that is the case, this is probably better:

```
\ttext=([^\t*])
```

Which basically says, find a tab followed by 'text=' and then capture everything up until the next tab.