# Lazy quantifier {,}? not working as I would expect

Tags: regex, lazy-evaluation

I have an issue with lazy quantifiers. Or most likely I misunderstand how I am supposed to use them.

Testing on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/)
My test string is let's say: `123456789D123456789`

`.{1,5}` matches `12345`

`.{1,5}?` matches `1`

I am OK with both matches.

`.{1,5}?D` matches `56789D` !! I would expect it to match `9D`

Thanks for clarifying this.

Comment: I didn't even know the `{x, y}` quantifier could be made lazy, thanks for asking this question !

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First and foremost, please **do not think of greediness and laziness in regex as means of getting the longest/shortest match**. "Greedy" and "lazy" terms only pertain to the *rightmost character* a pattern can match, it does not have any impact on the leftmost one. When you use a lazy quantifier, it will guarantee that the end of your matched substring will be the first found one, not the last found one (that would be returned with a greedy quantifier).

The regex engine analyzes a string from left to right. So, it searches for the first character that meets the pattern and then, once it finds the matching substring, it is returned as a match.

Let's see how it parses the string with `.{1,5}D`: `1` is found and `D` is tested for. No `D` after `1` is found, the regex engine expands the lazy quantifier and matches `12` and tries to match `D`. There is `3` after `2`, again, the engine expands the lazy dot and does it 5 times. After expanding to the max value, it sees there is `12345` and the next character is not `D`. Since the engine reached the max limiting quantifier value, the match is failed, next location is tested.

The same scenario happens with the locations up to `5`. When the engine reaches `5`, it tries to match `5D`, fails, tries `56D`, fails, `567D`, fails, `5678D` - fails again, and when it tries to match `56789D` - Bingo! - the match is found.

This makes it clear that a **lazily quantified subpattern at the beginning of a pattern will act "greedily" by default, that is, it will not match the shortest substring**.

Here is a visualization from [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/xR2nW6/1):

[image]

Now, here is **a fun fact**: `.{1,5}?` at the end of the pattern will always match 1 character (if there is any) because the requirement is to match at least 1, and it is sufficient to return a valid match. So, if you write [`D.{1,5}?`](https://regex101.com/r/xR2nW6/2), you will get `D1` and `D6` in `123456789D12345D678904`.

**Fun Fact 2**: In .NET, you can "ask" the regex engine to analyze the string from right to left with the help of `RightToLeft` modifier. Then, with `.{1,5}?D`, you will get `9D`, see [this demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=.%7B1%2C5%7D%3FD&i=123456789D&o=r&s=10).

**Fun fact 3**: In .NET, `(?<=(.{1,5}?))D` will capture `9` into Group 1 if `123456789D` is passed as input. This happens because of the way the [lookbehind is implemented in .NET regex](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) (.NET reverses the string as well as the pattern inside the lookbehind, then attempts to match that single pattern on the reversed string). And in Java, `(?<=(.{1,5}))D` (the greedy version) will capture `9` because it tries all the possible fixed-width patterns in the range, from the shortest to the longest, until one succeeds.

And a solution is: if you know you need 1 character followed with `D`, just use

```
/.D/
```

Comment: Why 9D is not matched given the range `{1,5}` in `.{1,5}?D`. Why is it taking 5 (maximum)  numbers, why not 1 (minimum) ?

Comment: @noob: Because "lazy" does equal "the shortest possible match". The engine works from left to right, so any match will have the left-most starting character. However, in some flavors, there is a way to get `9D`, like in .NET (see Fun Fact 2).

Comment: I mean to say `.{1,5}` is greedy, it matches `12345`.  `.{1,5}?` is lazy, it matches `1`. Then shouldn't `.{1,5}?D` be lazy too and match `9D` ? But it becomes greedy and matches `56789D`.

Comment: Again, you are confusing notions. Greedy and lazy only pertains to the rightmost character a pattern can match, it does not have anything to do with the leftmost one. I should add this to the beginning of my answer.

Comment: @noob I suggest you to play a bit with this [Debuggex link](https://www.debuggex.com/r/s6u4IXIm9ha2i87N) (especially the cursors) to have a graphic explanation of this functionality

Comment: @Thomas: I did grasped a bit from Wiktor's answer. And sure I will check it out.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Thx for explanations, so which regexp will match 9D? 
Because this is the result I need to get :)

Comment: I wrote it at the bottom: `.D`. Here is the [**demo**](https://regex101.com/r/aP2uD9/1). If you are using PCRE regex, it is the only way.

Comment: lol yep of course :). Obvious answer but great explanations thx again Wiktor.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for the great explanation :)

Answer (score 2):

Your regex is

```
.{1,5}?D
```

matches

```
123456789D123456789
    ------
```

But you said you expected `9D` because using of "non-greedy quantifier".

Anyway, how about this?

```
D.{1,5}?
```

What is a result of matching?

Yes! as you expected it matches

```
123456789D123456789
         --
```

So, WHY?

OK, The first, I think you need to understand that normally regex engine will read characters from left to right-hand side of an input string. Considering your example which using non-greedy quantifier, once engine is matched

```
123456789D123456789
    ------
```

It will not go further to

```
123456789D123456789
     -----
123456789D123456789
      ----
...
123456789D123456789
        --
```

Because regex engine will evaluate text as less as possible, this is why it also called "Lazy quantifiers".

And it also work in the same way on my regex `D.{1,5}?` which should not go further to

```
123456789D123456789
         ---
123456789D123456789
         ----
...
123456789D123456789
         ------
```

But stop at the first match

```
123456789D123456789
         --
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string containing numbers followed by a non-numeric, the minimum set of {1,5}? would always be 1 (so it's not necessary to have the range.) I don't think the lazy operator is actually working as we think on the numeric range.

If you make the first \d+ greedy, as below you'll get the minimum number of digits before the D.

`(\d+)(\d{1,5}D)`
Matches 9D in the second group

If you make the first set of numbers lazy, then you'll get the maximum number of digits (5)

`(\d+?)(\d{1,5}D)`
Matches 56789D in the second group

I think these regex expressions might be more in line with what you need.