# Scala Regexp: find all matches in a string that contain predefined token or any word which consists of 2-4 characters

Tags: java, regex, scala

I have to find all matches in a string that contains predefined tokens (AB- or BCC- or CDD-) or [A-Z]{2,4}-. Predefined tokens have a highest priority.
I mean:

`regex.findAllIn("XBCC-").toList` must always return List(BCC-), not List(XBCC-)

but:

`regex.findAllIn("XTEST-").toList` must return List(TEST-)

I try something like that:

```
val regex = "((AB|BCC|CDD)|[A-Z]{2,4})-".r
```

But it doesn't work properly.

Comment: You should do that in 2 steps. First, check with the predefined values, then use the generic one.

Comment: Is it impossible do in one regular expression?

Comment: No, it is not possible with Scala regex. See [some explanations here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35606426/order-of-regular-expression-operator/35606463#35606463), and here is a [related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35944441/lazy-quantifier-not-working-as-i-would-expect/35944635#35944635) showing how regex engine works. The whole problem is that your expression is not anchored on the left, and the engine can start matching with any alternative branch at each location.

Comment: Well, on second thought, you might try to restrict the `[A-Z]{2,4}`: [`(?:(?:AB|BCC|CDD)|(?![A-Z]*(?:AB|BCC|CDD)-)[A-Z]{2,4})-`](https://regex101.com/r/vN2nW6/2)

Comment: Why do you need to do it with  a single regex? You're definitely making things hard for yourself.

Comment: Thank you, it seems to be working!

Comment: Maybe you are right, and to use one regex more complicated for code comprehension. And I'll use 2 rexep to find all my tokens in text. But your can post your answer to my question. It is correct, I suppose)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't believe the naysayers. This can quite easily be done with regex:

```
(?!\w+(?:AB|BCC|CDD)-)[A-Z]{2,4}-
```

See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/vN2nW6/3).

The lookahead assertion here makes sure the pattern doesn't match if `AB-`, `BCC-` or `CDD-` is present later in the text.

---

Explanation:

```
(?!                assert that there is no...
   \w+             ...sequence of characters...
   (?:AB|BCC|CDD)  ...followed by AB, BCC, or CDD...
   -               ...and a dash
)
[A-Z]{2,4}-        then simply match 2 to 4 characters before a dash
```