# How to make the middle capture group work when surrounded by wildcards?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

I use Regex quite a bit. I'm no master, but I've surprised myself with how difficult this has been.

---

We have a Regex string like this:

```
^(?:remind me ).*? (to|that|about|its|it's)? ?(.*)$
```

I want it to match both of the following strings, *and* assign some value to the first capture group.

- remind me in 24 hours test
- remind me in 24 hours **to** test

Assigning this little "to" to the first capture group is proving very difficult.

---

I could work-around this by doing two passes like below and then checking if the result is `null` or not, but that seems like madness, so I'm hoping to learn a better approach to this.

```js
const regex1 = /^(?:remind me ).*? (to|that|about|its|it's)? ?(.*)$/i
const regex2 = /(to|that|about|its|it's) ?(.*)$/i

const matches1 = 'remind me in 24 hours to test'.match(regex1)[2]
const matches2 = matches1.match(regex2)

console.log(matches2)
// String1 output: null
// String2 output: [ 'to test', 'to', 'test', index: 9, input: '24 hours to test', groups: undefined ]
```

---

On related questions:

I've seen numerous other questions about this - but none of the "solutions" seem applicable here, as most of the answers are tailored to the user's specific issue, and I haven't been able to figure out how to fix our issue using them as a reference.

I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35944635), and it improved my understanding of greedy vs lazy, but did not help me understand how to resolve my issue without crummy code.

---

**TLDR:** Desired results would look like below, matching the whole string with **to** in the first capture group. The contents of the second capture group are not important to us except that the group is not empty.

[image]

Comment: How about [something like this?](https://regex101.com/r/0fTXQF/1)

Comment: That's wonderful! I was so close with my attempt like `^(?:remind me ).*? (?:(to|that|about|its|it's))? ?(.*)$`. I'll accept as an answer if you could include a brief explanation of why your shared regex works, but putting the `.*? ` outside of the non-capture group doesn't work.

Comment: I tried to explain it better now. Interesting question for understanding also for me! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works if you remove the optional quantifier from the *first capturing group* and put `.*?` together with the capture group into another non-capturing group and make this outer group *optional*:

```
^remind me +(?:.*?\b(to|that|about|its|it's)\b *)?(.*)$
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/G17vNt/3) (I also did some little changes like adding word boundaries, change quantifiers for variable space and remove the non-capture group at start, that looks unneeded)

---

To understand why this works, first have a look at the simple pattern `(a)?` and how this results in [one capture of `a` and three empty matches in `abc`](https://regex101.com/r/DDD0nL/1) while getting [four empty matches in e.g. `xyz`](https://regex101.com/r/G4K8uK/1).

Simplifying your current pattern to e.g. [`^a.*?(b)?(.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/ygCLjr/1) investigate this at the [regex101 debugger](https://regex101.com/r/ygCLjr/1/debugger) and click the *matches tab* on the left side. For the string `abc` the regex parser first matches `a`. The next character `b` matches the optional group and the capture succeeds. Using the same pattern on another string `acbc`, after matching the first `a` the next character is a `c`. Because `b` is *optional* it "fits in" between `a` and the adjacent `c` (click around *step 7* at match 2) and won't get captured.

But refactoring this pattern to [`^a(?:.*?(b))?(.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/XM3wXD/1) and now looking into the [debugger](https://regex101.com/r/XM3wXD/1/debugger) (watch steps 3 to 12) you can see that *at the same position* after the first `a` the grouped `(?:.*?(b))?` part fits in here for  both test strings. The first group captures the substring before proceeding in the pattern.

---

With your current pattern there are even some strings that will the first group let capture ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/gnsoMr/1)).

Comment: ohhhh does JS supports `.*?` one that's nice to know. I thought its only for GNU specific, thanks for sharing.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 JS afaik just don't support possessive quantifier but sure [*lazy*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) yes :) If you look at [regular-expressions.info into quantifiers](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html) and select JS all supported are listed.