# How to match text between words using regex?

Tags: python, regex

I would like to match text text between pre-processor defines in Python.

In this example I'd like to match to remove text so lines 2..4 would be removed, eg:

```
#if 1
#  if 0
Remove me
#  endif
Keep me
#endif
```

Using this regex, it removes text, but the `.*` doesn't stop at the first `#endif`:

```
def remove_if0(string):
    pattern = r"(^\s*#\s*if\s+0\b.*^\s*#\s*endif\b)"
    regex = re.compile(pattern, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
    return regex.sub("", string)
```

Is there a way to match against pairs without the DOTALL reading past a term? eg `^\s*#\s*endif\b`.

I tried `(?!word)`, eg: `(?!^\s*#\s*endif\b)*` - but it didn't work.

Comment: Use [ungreedy `.*?`](https://regex101.com/r/WWtJW4/3/)

Comment: Thats it! Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx: Smallest possible match or nongreedy match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919982/regex-smallest-possible-match-or-nongreedy-match)

Comment: The duplicate has the same answer but the question is much more spesific (also `.net`, although that doesn't always matter).

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to use ungreedy `.*?` (thanks to @bobble-bubble)

Here is a working Python function:

```
def remove_if0(string):
    pattern = r"(^\s*#\s*if\s+0\b.*?^\s*#\s*endif)"
    regex = re.compile(pattern, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
    return regex.sub("", string)
```